# How can I call parameterised method in salesforce apex class

Tags: salesforce, apex

Greetings to All!
I am a beginner in Salesforce. And I was trying to use `enum` in my Salesforce Apex Class, but I got compiler errors. actually, I used parameterised method with `List<Account>` return type.

I tried to call this method but got an error like:-

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void enumEX() from the
>   type EnumClassEx

And I am not getting how can I resolve this and call parameterized method.

It would be grateful for me if you people help me to solve this. 
Thanks for your kind help :)

**Apex class is:-**

```
public class EnumClassEx 
{

    public enum Relationship_Status {Married,Single,Committed}
    public enum SLA {SILVER,GOLD}
    public EnumClassEx()
    {
        List<Relationship_Status> status= Relationship_Status.values();
        System.debug('Relationship Status is=='+status);
        System.debug('Relationship Status value index is=='+Relationship_Status.Committed.ordinal());
        System.debug('Relationship Status name is==' +Relationship_Status.Single.name()); 
    }
     public static List<Account> enumEX(SLA sla)
       {
        if(EnumClassEx.SLA.SILVER == sla)
          {
            return [SELECT ID FROM Account WHERE SLA__c= 'SILVER'];
           }
        else if(EnumClassEx.SLA.GOLD == sla)
           {
            return [SELECT ID FROM Account WHERE SLA__c= 'GOLD'];
           }
        else
          {
            return null;
          }            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to call the method like this

```
EnumClassEx.enumEX(EnumClassEx.SLA.SILVER);
```

Comment: I called like this...but its not working... @Gareth Jordan

Comment: I created your class above and ran the code I suggested wrapped in a debug statement

System.debug(EnumClassEx.enumEX(EnumClassEx.SLA.SILVER));

 and got this response:

13:14:19:012 USER_DEBUG [1]|DEBUG|(Account:{Id=00141000005yBfyAAE}, Account:{Id=00141000005yBfzAAE}, Account:{Id=00141000005yBg0AAE})

Comment: Are you sure that you have data to match the query that you are running?

Comment: Thank you so much @Gareth Jordan :) now the code is working...and yes I have data that is also matching..can you explain to me why have you called like this?

Comment: Your enumEX method is a static method, so  you dont need to instantiate the class to call it, so it's called like EnumClassEx.enumEX(...).  For the argument it takes the SLA enum, but that enum is inside of the EnumClassEx class, so it's kinda like a namespace, so you must as enums are treated like inner classes, so in your case it would be  OuterClass.Enum.EnumOption (EnumClassEx.SLA.SILVER)

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Gareth Jordan for your kind help..now I got it.. :)